# Longer Summer Days, Longer Winter Nights in the Temperate Zone

Tags: environment, climate, seasons

Earth in this scenario still rotates once every 24 hours, and the temperate zone still has four seasons, each one lasting three months.

But in this scenario, a temperate summer has the sun shining for 18 hours, whereas a temperate winter has the sun shining for only six.

What kind of axial tilt would allow such a transition?  And how would ecosystems be affected?

Answer (score 1):

Same axial tilt as Earth (23,4°) will do just fine.

If your looking for a place with 18h of daylight in summer and 6h in winter, look for [this graphic](http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e1/Hours_of_daylight_vs_latitude_vs_day_of_year_cmglee.svg/2000px-Hours_of_daylight_vs_latitude_vs_day_of_year_cmglee.svg.png&imgrefurl=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equinox&h=1125&w=2000&tbnid=QwBUNhf4AtkDFM:&docid=x9M3icVHrHSYaM&ei=8OgaVrnEI8H6-AHLq6XoAQ&tbm=isch&ved=0CB4QMygBMAFqFQoTCLn8g-fBu8gCFUE9Pgody1UJHQ).

[image]

<sup>Image used courtesy of Wikipedia user Cmglee under [the Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 3.0 Unported license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.en).</sup>

Basically, every place on Earth near the 60th parallel will have these characteristics regarding the daylight duration.

Comment: That's only one degree.  This scenario is if such solar influence affects the whole zone.

Comment: @JohnWDailey you understand that the axial tilt is the cause of the change in seasons and without it, we would not have seasons?

Comment: Furthermore, different latitudes will have a different daytime "transition". With no tilt, there is no transition. Whit a different tilt, the transition your looking for will be located at another latitude.

Comment: @JohnWDailey - "That's only one degree. This scenario is if such solar influence affects the whole zone" But the intensity of solar radiation is completely irrelevant to day/night lengths.  It is not possible to have a "temperate zone" with the numbers you want. The length of day and night are controlled entirely by axial tilt and latitude. Unless you know both, you cannot know the durations (except for zero tilt, of course.)